# Eclipse Plugin Cancel Completely

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, terminate, eclipse-pde, cancellation

When in an eclipse plugin you implement Job and Override the run()-method, you can make changes to the parameter IProgressMonitor and skip tasks if the user pushed Cancel like this:

```
        if (!monitor.isCanceled()){
            monitor.subTask("Doing stuff");
            //do task
        } else {
            returnedStatus = Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
        }
```

But that means that at least the currently active task has to be finished before skipping the rest. Is there any way to completely abort the plugin activity and execute a finally block when the user pushes cancel, without waiting for the next `if (!monitor.isCanceled())`  and without subdividing your whole program into subTasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your Job has to be the one to react to cancellation, so you need to either break the job up into tasks for which you can report progress with `worked()` and check cancellation, or you have to send around sub-progressmonitors and do the same thing.

https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate, but thanks for clarification.